# how to get absolute path from relative path in command line

Tags: linux, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I run this command "httpd -d ./inst2 -k start" to boot Apache Server, and I can see this command line through "ps -ef | grep httpd". My question is if i don't know the absolute path, is there a way to get the absolute path of "./inst2"?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to **GUESS** what the absolute path is by examining the pseudo symbolic link `/proc/PID/cwd` where `PID` can be determined from the `ps` output: `ls -l /proc/PID/cwd`. But please note that **it is just the current working directory and your path may be resolved against any other directory, so it is just a guess**.

Another option, if your program opens some files using this relative path and in fact you need to determine the full path of such files, you can enumerate files currently open by some process using `/proc/PID/fd` pseudo directory: `ls -l /proc/PID/fd`. But, of course, the file can already be closed by the time of executing `ls`. And I don't know what it will show if the open file was moved to some other place.

Comment: Thank you , i tried that, but it just display "/", however,  this is not related to relative path "./inst2"

Comment: i did some research, and i think /proc/pid/environ can do that, you can locate "PWD=xxx" section in that file

Comment: @sudo AFAIK `/proc/pid/environ` lists the environment variables of a process. I fear, `PWD` here is just some variable set by `bash` or other shell at the time when the process was started. But, at least, it is another way to guess.

Comment: can you give a sample to the sentence "But please note that it is just the current working directory and your path may be resolved against any other directory, so it is just a guess." In which case, it can be some other unrelated directory?

Comment: @sudo It is **current** working directory, so relative path in question could be resolved against another directory that **was current** previously. Another option, some path can be manually resolved (not using regular `open`, `stat`, etc. syscalls) against, for example, installation directory, but hope it will be stated explicitly in the docs on that program:)

Comment: see the PWD I mentioned in /proc/pid/environ can be used to locate the absolute path of "./inst2" because it's written when that cmdline is executed. So i think it's reliable

Comment: Supposing it was bash who launched the httpd and who set the PWD, this path looks very likely.

Comment: Yes, "./inst2" is actually relative to the working directory when booting the server from bash. In addition, this is applicable to RHEL-like system and regular Apache

Answer (score -1):

To get the absolute path of a file/directory even you can execute following command on linux.

1. find $HOME -type f -name "*inst2*" (for file)
2. find $HOME -type d -name "*inst2*" (for directory)

this can give you absolute path for any file or directory. 
If the file is not in your home then use **sudo** in front of commands and replace **$HOME** by **/**.

Comment: Hi thanks for that, however, this is not an efficient and reliable solution

Comment: I did some research, and i think /proc/pid/environ can do that, you can locate "PWD=xxx" section in that file